# :nth-child() issue selecting every second div

Tags: php, html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to give every second div in my container a different background color compared to the first one. The issue I have is, that there is a JavaScript code in between the divs. Here is an example:

```
echo '<div class="holder">';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript"></script>';
    echo '<div class="list_item"></div>';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript"></script>';
    echo '<div class="list_item"></div>';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript"></script>';
    echo '<div class="list_item"></div>';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript"></script>';
    echo '<div class="list_item"></div>';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript"></script>';
    echo '<div class="list_item"></div>';
echo '</div>';
```

When I now add the following css code:

```
.holder .list_item:nth-child(even) {
    background-color:#fff;
}
```

it will give all of the divs the white background color.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this???

P.S: I changed the css code to nth-child(odd) as well to test it. But that didn't work either.

Comment: here's another way https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GmbaOB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `nth-of-type` instead of `nth-child`. This will only take `<div>` tags into account, regardless of what is in between of them.

Comment: @Dennis I’ve made a small correction. `nth-of-type` actually only checks the tag type, not the whole selector.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The [**`:nth-child()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) pseudo-class will count *all siblings* sharing the same parent.

Since you have multiple element types in the container, and you are targeting only the divs, you can skip over the `script` elements by using [**`:nth-of-type()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) instead.

`:nth-of-type()` matches only elements of the same type.

So when you say:

> I am trying to give every second div in my container a different background color compared to the first one.

Try something like this:

```
div:nth-of-type(even)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two child elements per entry. There is a script child and a div child. You could either address the divs using `:nth-child(4n+1)` (or +3 for even), or you could use the :nth-of-type selector to just address the div elements:

```
:nth-of-type(odd / even) {…}
```